# Is this a reliable way to kill a child process if it hangs? [Perl]

Tags: perl, fork

I know that using shell commands within perl should be avoided, but this is a quick script that I'm writing to test failures - it's not permanent.

The goal here is to fork a child and have it run some queries against a database. Then after 10 seconds (which is ample time for the child to exit normally), the parent runs `ps` to see if the child still exists (if it does, it's hanging), looks at the return code in `$?` and decides what to do accordingly. The code:

```
$pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    # in child
    run_some_queries()....
    exit(0);
} else {
    # in parent
    sleep 10;
    chomp($return = `ps -p $pid`);
    if ($return == 0) {
        # child still running
        # kill child
    } else {
        # child exited graceully
    }
}
```

Is there a hidden race condition that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said it; shell is to be avoided as it is more complex, more error prone, and requires proper output handling (`$return == 0` doesn't do what you want).

```
my $is_alive = kill(0, $pid);
if ($is_alive) { kill child ... }
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but it always return 1. It seems like the process is a zombie when `kill()` is called so it gets counted. Am I somehow not terminating the child correctly? Why is it still in the process table after an `exit(0)`?

Comment: @MaxMackie check [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) if you're sure that child did exit(0).

Answer (score 1):

The sleeps as little as possible rather than unconditionally wait 10 seconds.

```
my %children;
local $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
   while (1) {
      my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
      last if $pid < 1;
      $children{$pid} = $?;
   }
};

my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
   ...
   exit();
}

my $end_time = time + 10;
while (!defined($children{$pid})) {
   my $sleep_time = $end_time - time;
   last if $sleep_time <= 0;

   #sleep($sleep_time);
   sleep(1);   # Mitigate race condition.
}

my $killkill;
while (!defined($children{$pid})) {
   kill($killkill++ ? 'TERM' : 'KILL', $pid);
   sleep(2);
}
```

The aforementioned race condition occurs when the signal comes in between the `defined($children{$pid})` check and the system call to `sleep`.